# Авторы и книги php

Tags: php

Я создаю `$data`, в которой будет записаны авторы и их книги. Я хочу в `'books'` в `'author'` записать автора, но почему-то не получается, что я делаю не так?

```php
$data = 
[
    'authors' => [
        [
            'Имя' => 'Николай Васильевич',
            'Email' => 'nikolaVaSiliev@mail.ru',
            'Год рождения' => 1809
        ]
    ],
    'books' => [
        'Название' => 'Мертвые души',
        'Год выпуска' => 1841,
        'author' => $data['authors'][0]
    ]
];

echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($data['authors'][0]);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну потому что в моменте `'author' => $data['authors'][0]` еще не существует.

Comment: @entithat а что тогда можно сделать? Мне нужно записать всё только в переменной $data

Comment: После создания `$data` уже добавлять.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во время создания массива, который *потом будет назначен переменной*, переменной $data еще не существует.

Сделайте `$data['books']['author'] = $data['authors'][0];` после инициализации, отдельным выражением.